# How do I convert a double indexed dictionary to an excel file using one key as row index and the other key as column index?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a double indexed dictionary with one index being the time and the other a particular energy producing machine. After running a program the dictionary values connected to the keys will be the values of fuel consumption for each machine at each hour. 
Now, I would like to transfer this into an excel file with the first key (time) as row values and the second key (machine type) as column values, filling the cells with the corresponding values.
How can I do this?

I tried looking in pandas documentation and/or other different solutions but none of them worked properly.

The dictionary is something like:

```py
d = {}
d['mach1',1] = 4
d['mach1',2] = 9
d['mach1',3] = 16
d['mach2',1] = 10
d['mach2',2] = 2
d['mach2',3] = 4
d['mach3',1] = 3
d['mach3',2] = 6
d['mach3',3] = 1
```

And I would like to have a database that looks like this:

```py
    mach1  mach2  mach3
1     4      10     3
2     9       2     6
3    16       4     1
```

How can I do this? Thank you in advance and sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ciao Andrea,
Starting from the dictionary you provided as an example:

1. Retrieving the names of columns and indexes:

   `col_name = list({x for (x,_) in list(d.keys())})
   index = list({y for (_,y) in list(d.keys())})`
2. Format data for pandas:

   `dd = {i: [] for i in col_name}
   for (col_id,row_id),v in d.items():
       dd[col_id].append(v)`
3. I create the df and set the index:

   `df = pd.DataFrame({ key:pd.Series(value) for key, value in dd.items() })
   df.index = index`
   `#    mach1  mach2  mach3`
   `# 1      4     10      3`
   `# 2      9      2      6`
   `# 3     16      4      1`
4. Do something with pandas df
5. Store df to csv file:

   `df.to_csv("myData.csv", sep=";")`
6. Open csv with Excel and do something
7. Load data from csv file:

   `df = pd.read_csv("myData.csv", sep=";", index_col=0)`

The complete code is available here:

```
def my_dict_to_df(d):
    col_name = list({x for (x,_) in list(d.keys())})
    index = list({y for (_,y) in list(d.keys())})
    dd = {i: [] for i in col_name}
    for (col_id,row_id),v in d.items():
        dd[col_id].append(v)
    df = pd.DataFrame({ key:pd.Series(value) for key, value in dd.items() })
    df.index = index
    return df

df = my_dict_to_df(d)
df.to_csv("myData.csv", sep=";")
```

**EDIT:** I thought the data had been ordered. Without this assumption, you need to order dictionary `d`, `col_name` and `index` at beginning:

```
def my_dict_to_df(d):
    d = dict(sorted(d.items()))
    col_name = sorted({x for (x,_) in list(d.keys())})
    index = sorted({y for (_,y) in list(d.keys())})
    dd = {i: [] for i in col_name}
    for (col_id,row_id),v in d.items():
        dd[col_id].append(v)
    df = pd.DataFrame({ key:pd.Series(value) for key, value in dd.items() })
    df.index = index
    return df
```

**Note1**: this is not the most efficient way to solve the problem. It is written in this to make it as comprehensible as possible

**Note2**: If you can, change the format of the input dictionary. It's unnecessarily complicated

**Note3**: It seems that you don't have very clear ideas, is this really what you need?

Comment: In your approach you rely on the order of elements in a set, but sets are unordered. You should sort `col_name` before assigning it to the columns of the resulting dataframe - which works at least if the original column names are sorted, too.

Comment: I considered that the data was ordered. Without this assumption, simply change the order of the two list `sorted(col_name)` and `sorted(index)`

Comment: Perhaps we run into misconception right now, so again in other words: correct, I'm assuming `['mach1',  'mach2',  'mach3']` to be ordered, too. But your implementation of `col_name` can be any order, because it is a set, casted to a list, and sets do not preserve order. In my case e.g., I simply copy pasted your function, ran it and the index and values of the resulting dataframe were correct, but the column names were `mach2  mach3  mach1`, i.e. wrong.

Comment: And no: not without, but _with_ this assumption adding `sorted(col_name)` and `sorted(index)` will assert that your output is correct. If the dict keys are _not_ sorted, sorting would even make the result wrong for sure.

Comment: Now I understand what you mean. Then just order the dictionary by key at the beginning of the function: `def my_dict_to_df(d):
    d = sorted(d) `. Now I edit the code. Thanks

Comment: Hmm, I don't think that this will work. 1. `sorted` returns a list (a sorted list of the dict-keys in this example), not a dictionary. 2. Even if you sort the dictionary - it is still quite new that dictionaries are ordered (I think since Python 3.4, IIRC...), i.e. there are still many installations out there which would create wrong results with code which relies on dicts being ordered...

Comment: Sorry I messed up in bringing the code back into the reply. Now works: `def my_dict_to_df(d): d = dict(sorted(d.items())) # other code`

Comment: Now you asserted a sorted dict as input - but the first issue still remains, because in this case the dict was already sorted... So you still have to add sorting to the index and columns lists.

Comment: If you do it like this you can leave the typecast to list away, as `sorted` returns a list anyway.

Comment: Thanks, I update the answer. I fixed the code a bit to generalize better.

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately the dictionary input is given from an optimization algorithm based on pyomo that works with multi-indexed dictionaries, so I have to deal with it I guess.
Anyway, thank you for the answer that solved my problem!

P.S. yes, that's exactly what I needed, sorry for not being clear. I'm new to stackoverflow and I don't have a solid coding background + I'm italian and my english is not good, so I'm trying to do my best :) Once again, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I also didn't get it to work with sth built-in or nice magically short...

However - you could do it "manually":

```
import pandas as pd

# first with constants for your example to get the point:
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['mach1', 'mach2', 'mach3'], index=[1, 2, 3])

# but of course better calculated for general case:
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=sorted(set([t[0] for t in d.keys()])), index=sorted(set([t[1] for t in d.keys()])))

#   mach1 mach2 mach3
# 1   NaN   NaN   NaN
# 2   NaN   NaN   NaN
# 3   NaN   NaN   NaN

for (k1, k2), v in d.items():
    df.loc[k2, k1] = v

#    mach1  mach2  mach3
# 1      4     10      3
# 2      9      2      6
# 3     16      4      1
```

then you can write csv for your Excel:

```
df.to_csv('export.csv')

# ,mach1,mach2,mach3
# 1,4,10,3
# 2,9,2,6
# 3,16,4,1
```

Comment: only works because its a trivial example with 1,2,3

Comment: @DerekEden No, I'm  just adressing the example in the first place. A general calculation is there, too.

Comment: No, the algorithm was there right from the beginning. It's exactly the same for the index like for the columns, except the index of the tuple.